# Debug StackOverflow Exception in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm building an ASP .NET Core MVC app, and I started encountering a random StackOverflowException, it happens when the aplication is idle rather than when I perform an Http request, so I'm having a hard time finding where the problem might be. I have the stack trace, and I see a recursion that should be whats causing the call stack to overflow, but it is from a method from framework itself, so I can't find the underlying cause.

I tried simplifying my ViewModels using DTOs instead of model objects, and at first it looked like it was working, the app was working 8 hours without crashing with the StackOverflowException (normally it happened 10-15 minutes from when I started the app), but now it started happening again, here is my call stack:

```
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethod(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.QCallModule module, int methodToken, System.IntPtr* typeInstArgs, int typeInstCount, System.IntPtr* methodInstArgs, int methodInstCount)   
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandleInternal(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule module, int methodToken, System.IntPtr[] typeInstantiationContext, int typeInstCount, System.IntPtr[] methodInstantiationContext, int methodInstCount) Línea 1405    
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandle(int methodToken, System.RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, System.RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) Línea 1390  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule scope, int typeMetadataToken) Línea 1743    
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeCustomAttributeData.RuntimeCustomAttributeData(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule scope, System.Reflection.MetadataToken caCtorToken, System.Reflection.ConstArray blob) Línea 273 
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeCustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule module, int tkTarget) Línea 213 
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeCustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributesInternal(System.RuntimeType target) Línea 22 
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.MemberInfo target) Línea 18  
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ProviderAliasUtilities.GetAlias(System.Type providerType) 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerRuleSelector.Select(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterOptions options, System.Type providerType, string category, out Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel? minLevel, out System.Func<string, string, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel, bool> filter)  
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.ApplyFilters(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerInformation[] loggers)  
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.RefreshFilters(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterOptions filterOptions)  
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitorExtensions.OnChange.AnonymousMethod__0(System.__Canon o, string _)  
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor<System.__Canon>.ChangeTrackerDisposable.OnChange(System.__Canon options, string name)  
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterOptions>.InvokeChanged(string name)   
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor<System.__Canon>..ctor.AnonymousMethod__6_2(string name)    
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration<string>.OnChangeTokenFired()    
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration<string>.RegisterChangeTokenCallback.AnonymousMethod__7_0(object s)  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.Invoke(System.Delegate d, object state, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource source) Línea 902  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.CallbackNode.ExecuteCallback.AnonymousMethod__9_0(object s) Línea 1139  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Línea 183 
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.CallbackNode.ExecuteCallback() Línea 1141   
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers(bool throwOnFirstException) Línea 722   
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.NotifyCancellation(bool throwOnFirstException) Línea 639    
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() Línea 221  
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RaiseChanged()   
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AddSource.AnonymousMethod__1()   
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange.AnonymousMethod__0_0(System.Action callback)   
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration<System.Action>.OnChangeTokenFired() 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration<System.Action>.RegisterChangeTokenCallback.AnonymousMethod__7_0(object s)   
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.Invoke(System.Delegate d, object state, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource source) Línea 902  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.CallbackNode.ExecuteCallback.AnonymousMethod__9_0(object s) Línea 1139  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Línea 183 
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.CallbackNode.ExecuteCallback() Línea 1141   
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers(bool throwOnFirstException) Línea 722   
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.NotifyCancellation(bool throwOnFirstException) Línea 639    
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() Línea 221  
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationProvider.OnReload()  
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(bool reload)    
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor.AnonymousMethod__1_1() 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange.AnonymousMethod__0_0(System.Action callback)   
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration<System.Action>.OnChangeTokenFired() 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration<System.Action>.RegisterChangeTokenCallback.AnonymousMethod__7_0(object s)   
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.Invoke(System.Delegate d, object state, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource source) Línea 902  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.Register(System.Delegate callback, object stateForCallback, System.Threading.SynchronizationContext syncContext, System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext) Línea 610  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationToken.Register(System.Delegate callback, object state, bool useSynchronizationContext, bool useExecutionContext) Línea 290  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationToken.UnsafeRegister(System.Action<object> callback, object state) Línea 248
```

and then it starts repeating this calls until it overflows:

```
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.CancellationChangeToken.RegisterChangeCallback(System.Action<object> callback, object state)    
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration<System.Action>.RegisterChangeTokenCallback(Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.IChangeToken token)  
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration<System.__Canon>.OnChangeTokenFired()    
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration<System.Action>.RegisterChangeTokenCallback.AnonymousMethod__7_0(object s)   
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.Invoke(System.Delegate d, object state, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource source) Línea 902  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.Register(System.Delegate callback, object stateForCallback, System.Threading.SynchronizationContext syncContext, System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext) Línea 610  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationToken.Register(System.Delegate callback, object state, bool useSynchronizationContext, bool useExecutionContext) Línea 290  
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationToken.UnsafeRegister(System.Action<object> callback, object state) Línea 248
```

Comment: Maybe you have a callback that calls itself, until you get the exception. Without code is hard to tell.

Comment: Please check https://www.died.tw/2021/09/net-6-systemstackoverflowexception.html